# Como alterar cor da linha do repeater em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como faço para alterar a cor da linha do `Repeater` em execução ?
As linhas do Repeater são carregadas através do que vem do banco de dados.

Exemplo:
Se houver 3 linhas, ao exibir no repeater, a primeira linha seja de uma cor, a segunda de outra e a terceira de outra etc.

Meu código:

//ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <tr>
  <!-- Coluna Compra -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>
  <!-- Coluna Devolução -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>
  <!-- Coluna Retorno -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>
  <!-- Coluna Venda -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>     
  <!-- Coluna Doação -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>
  <!-- Coluna Reenvio -->
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Qtde.</i></td>
   <td class="aFaturarTopo"><i>Valor</i></td>
  </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="tbFundoH">
      <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Categorias") %>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
    <!-- Coluna Compra -->
    <td id="colCompraQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label8" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdCompraCat") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td id="colCompraValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorCompraCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
  <!-- Coluna Devolução -->
    <td id="colDevolucaoQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label35" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdDevolucaoCat") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td id="colDevolucaoValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label47" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorDevolucaoCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
  <!-- Coluna Retorno -->
    <td id="colRetornoQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label48" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdRetornoCat") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td id="colRetornoValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label49" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorRetornoCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
 <!-- Coluna Venda -->
   <td id="colVendaQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
   <asp:Label ID="Label50" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdVendaCat") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
   <td id="colVendaValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label51" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorVendaCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
   </td>
 <!-- Coluna Doação -->
   <td id="colDoacaoQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
   <asp:Label ID="Label52" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdDoacaoCat") %>'></asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td id="colDoacaoValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
   <asp:Label ID="Label53" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorDoacaoCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
   </td>
  <!-- Coluna Reenvio -->
    <td id="colReenvioQtdeCat" class="tbFundoH">
    <asp:Label ID="Label54" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qtdReenvioCat") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
      <td id="colReenvioValorCat" class="tbFundoH">
     <asp:Label ID="Label55" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorReenvioCat")).Replace("R$", "") %>'></asp:Label>
     </td>
     </tr>                             
       </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: O que seria esse tempo de execução? Algum link, no carregamento ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @Marconi Não, As linhas do repeater são carregadas de acordo o que vem do banco de dados. Tipo carregam 3 linhas, preciso que a primeira fique tipo cinza claro, a segunda cinza escuro, terceira cinza claro etc.

Comment: Faz essa configuração linha a linha no evento Item_DataBound do Repeater

Comment: @Marconi pode me dizer como faz ?

Comment: A resposta abaixo não te ajuda @AndreeH?

Comment: @Marconi, não pq será só nas linhas do ItemTemplate e não no repeater todo. Tipo uma linha com uma cor, a outra com outra cor. É possível fazer isso com Item_DataBound ?

Comment: @AndreeH Se precisa para o cabeçalho (`thead`) e rodapé (`tfoot`) também, é só não usar o seletor `tbody`.

Answer (score 3):

A julgar pelos `<tr>` e `<td>` no `Repeater`, você terá uma tabela por fora do `Repeater`. Faça por CSS, colocando a class na tabela:

HTML:

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <asp:repetear..
    ...
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-striped tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #cor-1;
}
.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #cor-2;
}
```